# Laptop keyboard - one "column" of keys not working

Tags: keyboard

I sold and shipped the English QWERTY keyboard of my used laptop from North America to Eastern Europe.

This keyboard came with a computer I bought new and I myself and nobody else used this keyboard/laptop until I shipped it. I never spilled any liquid or powder on it. The keyboard has never given me problem and it is not from a bin of hundreds of other used keyboards.  Alright it wasn't the best packaging in the world, but I did enclose it in foam and cardboard.

When it got there, my buyer told me that the **0** (zero), **P**, **:**, and **?** keys are not functioning.

What troubleshooting steps can I tell my buyer?  Or should I write this off at this point as a $20 loss?

Comment: not working = not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's faulty out of the box.  Take it back, let them test it on their computer if necessary, and have them replace it.  In most countries, the shop must replace goods believed to be faulty out of the box.  It's not an uncommon occurance.